# Watching ng-show in directive works reverse

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do some logic, when my directive is shown or hidden. But as you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h34o3jnL/), the visibility of the element is reported wrong.

What do I miss here?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='testController'>
    <dialog ng-show='showDialog'>
      <p>
        I'm a dialog
      </p>
    </dialog>
    <button ng-click='showHideDialog()'>
      Show/Hide
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('dialog', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: false,
    template: '<div class="dialog">' +
      '<div class="overlay"></div>' +
      '<div class="body" ng-transclude>' +

      '</div>' +
      '</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      scope.$watch(function() {
        return element.is(':visible')
      }, function() {
        dialog = element;
        console.log('visibility of dialog changed to ', element.is(':visible'));
      });
    }
  };
});
app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
  $scope.showHideDialog = function() {
    $scope.showDialog = !$scope.showDialog;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your code on the `directive`side including a `directive`scope object for `ngShow`. After updated your excisting `scope.$watch` to watch the `ngShow` value for change.

**VIEW**

```
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='testController'>
    <dialog ng-show='showDialog'>
      <p>
        I'm a dialog
      </p>
    </dialog>
    <button ng-click='showHideDialog()'>
      Show/Hide
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER & DIRECTIVE**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('dialog', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        ngShow:'='
    },
    template: '<div class="dialog">' +
      '<div class="overlay"></div>' +
      '<div class="body" ng-transclude>' +

      '</div>' +
      '</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      scope.$watch('ngShow',function() {
        console.log('visibility of dialog changed to ', element.is(':visible'));
      }, function() {
        console.log('visibility of dialog changed to ', element.is(':visible'));
      });
    }
  };
});
app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
  $scope.showHideDialog = function() {
    $scope.showDialog = !$scope.showDialog;
  };
});
```

[JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7sr1o2gL/)

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want to introduce a scope on his directive. `scope: false` is very explicit.